# sorting a nested NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

the `NSMutableArray` I want to sort looks like this:

```
 (
        {
            "title" = "Bags";
            "price" = "$200";
        },
        {
            "title" = "Watches";
            "price" = "$40";
        },
        {
            "title" = "Earrings";
            "price" = "$1000";
        }
 )
```

It's an `NSMutableArray` which contain a collection of `NSMutableArray`s. I want to sort it by `price` first then by `title`.

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortByPrices = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"price" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *sortByTitle = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES];

[arrayProduct sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortByPrices,sortByTitle,nil]];
```

However, that didn't seems to work, how to sort a nested `NSMutableArray`?

Comment: How didn't it work, what did you have before and after and how did you do the sort?

Comment: It rather looks like array with dictionaries inside

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
    NSMutableArray  *arrayProducts = [@[@{@"price":@"$200",@"title":@"Bags"},@{@"price":@"$40",@"title":@"Watches"},@{@"price":@"$1000",@"title":@"Earrings"}] mutableCopy];

    NSSortDescriptor *priceDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@""
                                                                 ascending:YES
                                                                comparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary  *dict1, NSDictionary *dict2) {
                                                                    return [dict1[@"price"] compare:dict2[@"price"] options:NSNumericSearch];
    }];

    NSSortDescriptor *titleDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES];



    [arrayProducts sortUsingDescriptors:@[priceDescriptor,titleDescriptor]];

    NSLog(@"SortedArray : %@",arrayProducts);
```

Comment: @Desdenova Thanks, don't know how it was missed. Copied directly from xcode.

Comment: '*' is missing before 'dict1'-->                                                                comparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary  dict1, NSDictionary *dict2) {

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the error is that `price` is a string. As such, it isn't compared numerically, but lexicographically. Try sorting the array using a comparator block and parsing the price inside that block instead:

```
[array sortUsingComparator:^(id _a, id _b) {
    NSDictionary *a = _a, *b = _b;

    // primary key is the price
    int priceA = [[a[@"price"] substringFromIndex:1] intValue];
    int priceB = [[b[@"price"] substringFromIndex:1] intValue];

    if (priceA < priceB)
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    else if (priceA > priceB)
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    else // if the prices are the same, sort by name
        return [a[@"title"] compare:b[@"title"]];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

[Apple doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Arrays.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000132-SW5)

This well help you